# how to print tickets with php?

Tags: php, web, web-development-server

I am a junior in PHP , now I have a project It consists of booking tickets and printing them ,I created a form to book the tickets and I have the ticket's design ,but I don't know how can I order the printer to print my data I saw this code before but I don't understand it .

```
$handle = printer_open("\\\\192.168.1.33_4\\Printer_Office");
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "raw"); 
printer_write($handle,$print_output); 
printer_close($handle);
```

so I need help to complete this project.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get the contents of the file you want to print. Since you have the designs ready, you can just use `get_file_contents` to get the content of the html file. If your designs are dynamicly generated by php, then you can either save it to a temporary file or use `get_file_contents` to get the contents of the url.

```
$print_output= get_file_contents("PATH TO HTML FILE"); 

$handle = printer_open("\\\\192.168.1.33_4\\Printer_Office");
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "raw"); 
printer_write($handle,$print_output); 
printer_close($handle);
```